# Working with Suppliers feeds and categories.

Tags: magento2

I use 3 different suppliers each having their own category structure, I have feeds set up with them that will be automatically imported into my store but how do i handle my own category structure? i.e. how would magento know where to put the products i'm importing?

I can include a column (categories) in each feed from the suppliers with their own category structure but that's the problem, they're all different and if I used them, categories will be all over the place.